# The Rational Root Theorem for two variables

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials, factoring

Let's say we have a rational polynomial in $k$ variables. We are only interested in rational solutions. If $k = 1$, name the variables ${x}$, if $k = 2$, name them ${x,y}$.

For $k = 1$, it can be done very fast. [The Rational Root Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) gives a set of candidates. But what for $k=2$? How can I split a polynomial into factors in this case?

Example: $$ax^2+bx+cy^2+dy+g=0$$ where $a,b,c,d,g$ are constants and $x,y$ are variables.
This equation has integer solutions if and only if the quadratic equation $$ax^2+bx+(cy^2+dy+g)=0$$ has integer solutions with respect to $x$. For this case, we can use The Rational Root Theorem for the **one variable** $x$.

My question: Is this approach valid.

Comment: Shockingly this is an open question; it is in fact not known whether there exists an algorithm for finding rational solutions to a polynomial in two variables.

Comment: Please do not use irrelevant tags.

Comment: Which tag strikes you as irrelevant, @TedShifrin?

Comment: @Chickenmancer I already edited the tags. Differential geometry was quite irrelevant.